# How to create a checkbox with a delete buttom

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, axios, click

How can I create a checkbox that work like 1) click edit buttom --> 2) show checkbox in front data (data was import form axios) --> 3) click checkbox to selete delete

html

```
<div class="gs-players-container">

        {{#each rooms}}

        <div class="player">
        {{addOne @index}} | {{alterName this}}
        
        <div style="margin:0" class="btn btn-small waves-effect waves-light remove-player">ลบผู้เล่น</div>
        </div>
        
        {{/each}}
```

---

JS code

```js
'click .remove-player'() {
        let check = load('กำลังลบผู้เล่น')
        axios.put(`${api_url}/my-gs/${this.id}`,
            { accept: 0 },
            { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('pitch_token') } 
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.data.status == 'success') {
                check.dismiss()
                getGS()
            } else {
                console.log(res.data);
                check.dismiss()
                tellErr('ล้มเหลว กรุณาลองใหม่อีกครั้ง')
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            check.dismiss()
            tellErr(`${err}`)
        })
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: please share the code you have done

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to remove the button when the checkbox is checked. Im not sure about what you're asking with the edit and show data checkboxes. It'll be easier if you can show us what you tried so far

```js
function DeleteBtn() {

  var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

  if (checkbox.checked == true) {
    var button = document.getElementById('btn');
    button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="DeleteBtn()" />

<input type="button" value="something" id="btn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[click edit buttom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNE8G.png) [show checkbox in front data (data was import form axios)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXj7J.png)[selete delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyY11.png)